# Update and replace datatable rows value throughout all columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, dataset

I have a one generic datatable which contains any number of columns and any number of rows, which i want to update at once through linq query if a row's column contains a quote (**"**).

e.g.

**A quick brown "fox" jumps over the lazy "dog"**

I want this to be

**A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog**

Snapshot

[image]

I have tried

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("display").Contains("\""));
```

In this case column name is **"display"** is the column name, which I don't want to mention. Because this is not fixed as this **quote (")** could be in any column's row.

My problem is that I cannot find that specific columns for which I have tried this. It will give me all columns but not that specific columns.

```
string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

Any hints? **I don't want this to be done with traditional foreach loop over columns and then on rows and replace text then**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
//get columns which are of type "string" and then get their names
var columnNames = dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.DataType == typeof(string)).Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList();

//get all dataTable's rows and with each column name (from previous step) get row's value of that column
// and if that value contains double qoutes, replace it with empty char :)
dt.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(
    r => columnNames.ForEach(c => r.SetField<string>(c, r.Field<string>(c).Replace("\"", ""))));

//or, as one-liner :)
dt.AsEnumerable().ToList()
    .ForEach(r => dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
        .Where(c => c.DataType == typeof(string))
        .Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList()
            .ForEach(c => r.SetField<string>(c, r.Field<string>(c).Replace("\"", ""))));
```

I'm guessing that could be achieved a bit more simplier, but this can give you an idea :)

Comment: :) thanks @Nino .. this worked like a magic.I was totally boggled for this one liner.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to get a list of all cells that contain a quote in your dataTable.

You can then do a ForEach on the result to get rid of the quotes.

```
var result = (from DataColumn column in table.Columns
             let columnName = column.ColumnName                     
             from DataRow row in table.AsEnumerable()
             where row[columnName].ToString().Contains("\"")
             select row[columnName]).ToList();
```